# Washing ones hands prior to Torah on this website

Tags: halacha, torah-study, netilat-yadayim-washing

Does one have to wash his hands before

1. reading
2. Writing a Question
3. Answering

A Halachic /Torah related post on Mi yodeya. This is assuming he didn't remember if he touched a covered area without washing his hands.

This is the source that led me to my queston:

אלו דברים צריכים נטילה במים: הקם מהמיטה, והיוצא מבית הכסא ומבית המרחץ, והנוטל ציפורניו, והחולץ מנעליו, והנוגע ברגליו, והחופף ראשו. ויש אומרים אף ההולך בין המתים. ומי שנגע במת, ומי שמפליא כליו, והמשמש מיטתו, והנוגע בכינה, והנוגע בגופו בידו. ומי שעשה אחת מכל אלו ולא נטל, אם תלמיד חכם הוא – תלמודו משתכח, ואם אינו תלמיד חכם 
– יוצא מדעתו - These things require him to wash his hands...Someone who touches his body with his hands etc.

Mishna Brura:במים – אף דלתפילה, וכל שכן לתורה- Wash with water - for teffila and how much more so for Torah.

I know for sure that Saying the Torah with ones lips is forbidden in the same way one Davens Amida, but is reading just thinking which is permitted? Or is writing also considered thinking as typing is not permanent text?

Note: sources must be included, and remember, you are not reading Torah material out loud in any of the above options.

Comment: According to SA ([OC §88](https://he.m.wikisource.org/wiki/שולחן_ערוך_אורח_חיים_פח#.D7.A1.D7.A2.D7.99.D7.A3_.D7.90)) it would appear to be permitted to listen to or study Torah w/o washing the hands.

Comment: can you pls clarify your q?

Comment: when you type on the computer it disapears when you go on another website this is non permanent writing. whilst i have a feeling but don't know a source writing torah on paper might need washing hands,  it could be writing impermanently  is permitted

Comment: I understand the implication of כתיבה ש(אינה) מתקיימת. I meant to question why writing wouldn't be permitted under OC §88. (I'm aware that some authorities prohibit e.g. Torah study when nails were cut and not yet washed, therefore I purposely phrased it as "According to SA...", IOW "מדינא".)

Comment: I'm not ignoring that סעיף (entirely). But bear in mind, if that סעיף is obsolete how is it reconciled with §88?

Comment: והמשמש מיטתו still needs to wash his hands for cleanliness i heard this was because of Ki Devar Hashem Bozoh, this is regardless of the state of tuma of the body

Comment: Succah 26aשכה ושמש מטתו בתפילין אינו אוהז לא
 ברצועה ולא בקציצה עד שיטול ידיו ויטלם מעשה מפני שהידים עסקניות הן: Rashiעסקניות הן. ושמא נגעו במקום
 הטינופת it seems were worried about clanliness with Devarim shebikdusha